# Capture Impala Job Status in Logs

Tags: logging, cloudera, impala

I have shell script that trigger Impala queries in CLI mode:

`impala-shell -i server -f query.sql`

How to capture the status of the Impala job into a log file, especially when it failed? And also, if it failed, automatically trigger the job to run it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use linux `tee` command to write output to a file:

```
impala-shell -i server -f query.sql | tee impala-output.log
```

For the completion status of impala-shell, a non-zero value of linux special variable `$?` will indicate an error.

```
if [ "$?" > 0 ]; then
    # do things to handle failure
fi
```

Comment: impala doesn't produce the stack while it's running the job in the command line. So there will not be any logs in the file. You catch the error with Unix $? but it just shows the error code.

Comment: @roh Impala shell produces (without --quiet option) tons of output to stdout which will contain some clues like SemanticException,  AnalysisException, Memory limit exceeded, etc. You can grep the output for any/all of these.

Answer (score 0):

When the impala command failed, you can see the reason of failure through the cloudera manager .Go to : `Cloudera Manager --> Impala (service) --> Queries`. From there you can choose a query & from the menu at the upper right corner choose details.